# MySQL: Joining a table with itself without using Distinct 

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my table structure

- fName *Friend's Name [Varchar]*
- fUID *Friend's ID [Int]*
- UID *User's ID [Int]*

pk [fUID, UID]

I want to get common friends of 2 persons.  I tried:

```
SELECT t1.fName,
       t1.fUID 
  FROM friends t1, 
       friends t2 
 WHERE t1.UID = X 
   AND t2.UID = X2
```

but it did not work :(  I'm getting same results repeatedly.

Some sample data

```
UID  Name  
----------
1    Mark  
2    Eduardo  
3    Dustin
```

`Friend Table`

```
UID  fUID  fName  
------------------
1    2     Eduardo   
2    1     Mark  
3    1     Mark  
1    3     Dustin
```

Comment: Is the friend relation bi-directional? BTW: horrible field names

Comment: Yup, bi-directional, why horrible ? :O i hate to use UID1, UID2 as of Facebook :P

Comment: **My QUERY works perfetly but requires DISTINCT and from my previous question i came to know DISTINCT is an evil, so need to avoid it.**

Comment: Why is `DISTINCT` evil? I doubt that. Sounds like someone's declaration of a best practice, but it's just their own dogmatic rule.

Comment: DISTINCT process the same data again and filters out if any. And if you look in my table there is no duplicate data, but it still returns duplicate data, it means the SQL is wrong.

Comment: @Sourav: The problem is primarily in your query. It doesn't contain a condition that would link the two subsets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you have two user IDs (X1 and X2), and you want to find all of the people who are friends with both of those people.

```
SELECT f1.fUID, f1.fName
FROM friends f1,
friends f2
WHERE f1.UID = X1
      AND f2.UID = X2
      AND f1.fUID = f2.fUID
```

Note: this assumes that all friend relationships are stored twice in the friends table, once in each direction. If not, it gets a little more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   SELECT DISTINCT t1.fName,t1.fUID 
     FROM friends t1, friends t2 
    WHERE t1.UID=<USER-ID-1>
      AND t2.UID=<USER-ID-2>
      AND t1.fUID = t2.fUID
      AND t1.UID <> t2.UID
```

Test Data setup:

```
CREATE TABLE Friends
(
    uID INT,
    fuID INT,
    fName VARCHAR(20)
)

INSERT INTO Friends
SELECT '1 ',' 2 ','Eduardo'
UNION
SELECT '2 ',' 1 ','Mark'
UNION
SELECT '3 ',' 1 ','Mark'
UNION
SELECT '1 ',' 3 ','Dustin' 


SELECT DISTINCT t1.fName,t1.fUID 
    FROM Friends t1, Friends t2 
 WHERE t1.UID=2
   AND t2.UID=3
     AND t1.fUID = t2.fUID
```

Comment: i tried but it returned an empty set. i've added sample data, please review

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.fName, t1.fUID FROM friends t1 WHERE t1.UID=X1
Union
SELECT t1.fName, t1.fUID FROM friends t1 WHERE t1.UID=X2
```

you can fetch mutual friends by using union query.

Comment: UNION will not work here because it will get a the record if it exists either in Set#1 or Set#1 but not necessarily both..

Comment: Unfortunately there is no INTERSECT clause available in MySQL

Answer (score 0):

```
select fName
from friends
where uid = FIRST_USER_ID
  and exists (
    select 1
    from friends sfriends
    where sfriends.fid = friends.fid
      and sfriends.uid = SECOND_USER_ID
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  f.fUID,
  u.Name
FROM (
  SELECT fUID
  FROM (
    SELECT
      CASE WHEN UID  IN (@X, @X2) THEN UID ELSE fUID END AS UID,
      CASE WHEN fUID IN (@X, @X2) THEN UID ELSE fUID END AS fUID
    FROM friends
    WHERE     (UID IN (@X, @X2) OR  fUID IN (@X, @X2))
      AND NOT (UID IN (@X, @X2) AND fUID IN (@X, @X2))
  ) s
  GROUP BY fUID
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT UID) = 2
) f
  INNER JOIN users u ON f.fUID = u.UID
```